# Adding a new key in JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have written a python script the aim of the script is to update a json file to key that can be consumed by my database.

The following is my code:

```
import json
import os

json_dir="/home/"
json_dir_processed="/home/new/"
for json_file in os.listdir(json_dir):
    if json_file.endswith(".json"):
        processed_json = "%s%s" % (json_dir_processed, json_file)
        json_file = json_dir + json_file
        print "Processing %s -> %s" % (json_file, processed_json)
        with open(json_file, 'r') as f:
            json_data = json.load(f)
            # replacement mapping
            update_map = {"grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmermobile":"grp_farmerdts/hh_id",
                          "grp_farmerdts/hh_region": "grp_farmerdts/region",
                          "grp_farmerdts/hh_district":"grp_farmerdts/district",
                          "grp_farmerdts/hh_ward":"grp_farmerdts/ward",
                          "grp_farmerdts/hh_village":"grp_farmerdts/village"}

            diff_keys = set(update_map.keys()) - set(json_data.keys())
            if not diff_keys:
                print("No Update to JSON keys")
            else:
                for k in diff_keys:
                   if update_map[k] in json_data:
                        json_data[k] = json_data[update_map[k]]
        with open(processed_json, 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
    else:
        print "%s not a JSON file" % json_file
```

The JSON output which i get after running this python script is as shown below: Some JSON files already have the keys i want to create so i only want to update when the expected keys are not available

```
{  
 ....
   "_bamboo_dataset_id": "",
    "hh_id": "0912017300",
    "hh_country": "1",
    "hh_region": "3",
    "hh_district": "20",
    "_submitted_by": null,
    "enumtype": "2",
    "hh_village": "2130",
    "_attachments": [],
    "regactivity": "3",
    "grpanimreg/grp_farmanimals/farmersanimalsyesno": "0",
    "_submission_time": "2019-11-13T08:16:54",
    "_version": "20190910",
    "_geolocation": [
        7.2098272,
        37.7733643
    ],
    "end_time": "2019-11-13T11:18:40.615+03",
    "_id": 809956
}
```

My expected output: my code does not seem to update new keys and i am unable to figure out why.

```
{  
     ....
       "_bamboo_dataset_id": "",
        "farmermobile": "0912017300",
        "hh_country": "1",
        "hh_region": "3",
        "hh_district": "20",
        "_submitted_by": null,
        "enumtype": "2",
        "hh_village": "2130",
        "_attachments": [],
        "regactivity": "3",
        "grpanimreg/grp_farmanimals/farmersanimalsyesno": "0",
        "_submission_time": "2019-11-13T08:16:54",
        "_version": "20190910",
        "_geolocation": [
            7.2098272,
            37.7733643
        ],
        "end_time": "2019-11-13T11:18:40.615+03",
        "_id": 809956
    }
```

What can i change in my code to get my expected output, This could be a simple error on my code any pointer to edit my would be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you please post the original `json` files to get the full picture? Also are you trying to replace/update keys? Or values?

Comment: i am unable to post the whole JSON, because i would have to come up with a description; i can send to you on a private chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue relates to the `with` statements. I recognize running into a similar issue before.

I think the `json_data` variable is not updated because it is only initialized inside the `with open(json_file, 'r') as f:`, in which it relies on the file `f` because of `json.load(f)`.

Maybe you can try indenting this part of code:

```
with open(processed_json, 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
```

so that it falls within the first `with` statement?

Something like this perhaps?

```
import json
import os

json_dir="/home/"
json_dir_processed="/home/"
for json_file in os.listdir(json_dir):
    if json_file.endswith(".json"):
        processed_json = "%s%s" % (json_dir_processed, json_file)
        json_file = json_dir + json_file
        print "Processing %s -> %s" % (json_file, processed_json)
        with open(json_file, 'r') as f:
            json_data = json.load(f)
            # replacement mapping
            update_map = {"grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmermobile":"grp_farmerdts/hh_id",
                          "grp_farmerdts/hh_region": "grp_farmerdts/region",
                          "grp_farmerdts/hh_district":"grp_farmerdts/district",
                          "grp_farmerdts/hh_ward":"grp_farmerdts/ward",
                          "grp_farmerdts/hh_village":"grp_farmerdts/village"}

            diff_keys = set(update_map.keys()) - set(json_data.keys())
            if not diff_keys:
                print("No Update to JSON keys")
            else:
                for k in diff_keys:
                   if update_map[k] in json_data:
                        json_data[k] = json_data[update_map[k]]
            print(json_data)
            with open(processed_json, 'w') as f:
                f.write(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
    else:
        print "%s not a JSON file" % json_file
```

Also, does it print the correct expected output if you do print(json_data) in the same place as where I put it in the snippet above?

Hope this helps!